# Cherrypy initalization of Monitor object

Tags: python, apache2, cherrypy, mod-python

I have an application that uses **cherrypy**. It is run with **mod_python** (which I know is deprecated) at apache2 server.

I want to use [Monitor plugin](http://cherrypy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/pkg/cherrypy.process.html#cherrypy.process.plugins.Monitor) to run periodic task. My problem is that initialization of cherrypy and Monitor object is done when first request is received. So periodic task is run too late.

Should I use PythonImporter? If so how it should be run?

Here is my configuration of mod_python

```
PythonPath "sys.path+['/home/user/path/' ]"
SetHandler python-program
PythonHandler cherrypy._cpmodpy::handler
PythonInterpreter interperter
PythonOption cherrypy.setup index::setup_server
```